# Torsion elements of general linear group over $\mathbf{Z}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and let $\mathbf{Z}_p$ denote the ring of $p$-adic integers. Suppose that $n$ is an integer with $p>n+1$. Then it's well-known that the general linear group ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ is $p$-torsion-free. (Indeed, note that there is no element in $\mathbf{Z}_p$ having order $p$ if $p\geq 3$. If ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ has an element $x$ of order $p$, then the minimal polynomial of $x$ must divide $t^p-1$ and hence it has degree $p-1$. Since the minimal polynomial of $x$ is of degree at most $n$, we see that $p-1\leq n$, which is a contradiction.) It leads to the following question:

> What happens for $p=2$? More precisely, denote by $T({\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_2))$ the set of torsion elements in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_2)$. When is $T({\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_2))$ a group? For example, is $T({\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_2))$ always a group? Or, $T({\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_2))$ cannot be a group for $n\geq 2$?

When $n=1$, we have $T({\rm GL}_1(\mathbf{Z}_2))=\{\pm 1\}$. Thus, we may assume that $n\geq 2$. Any comments or references would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})^{torsion}$ is already not a group. Did you mean the $p^\infty$ torsion? If so then the product of two $4$-torsion elements of $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ is not torsion.

Comment: @reuns Yes, you're right. $T({\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_2))$ (even more, $2$-torsion elements of ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_2)$) cannot be a group for all $n\geq 2$.

Comment: If $M \equiv I_n \pmod{4}$, you can easily see that $v_2(M^2-I_n)=1+v_2(M-I_n)$ (for the natural meaning of $v_2$). In particular, $M$ can’t be $2^{\infty}$-torsion. So if $\Gamma \leq GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a finite $2$-group, then the mod $4$ maps is an embedding $\Gamma \to GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$. In particular, any two distinct $2^{\infty}$-torsion elements that are congruent mod $4$ generate a group containing some non-$2$-torsion elements.